# Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app call touch keyboard

Tags: c#, keyboard, uwp

I have a question:
I develop app UWP for win10 (c#). I launch the app on  Standalone Touch Monitor with single touch (touching emulate mouse, but it's not sensor input in win10).
When I set focus in textbox, sensor keyboard doesn't pop up. As an alternative I want to call sensor keyboard by `TextBox1.GotFocuse` event for example. I use 
[InputPane class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
textBox1.GotFocus += (s_focus, e_focus) =>
  {
     InputPane pane = InputPane.GetForCurrentView();
     tovary_brutto.PreventKeyboardDisplayOnProgrammaticFocus = true;
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pane.TryShow());
  };
```

but fucntion TryShow return FALSE value and keyboard doesn't show up. Can somebody offer any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 OS Decides when and when not to open touch keyboard. But there is a setting for this.

[See this post from WindowsCentral](http://www.windowscentral.com/auto-display-touch-keyboard-windows-10-desktop-mode)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I know about this settings. But these settings show on tablet or other touch panel. On my monitor (http://posiflex.com.ua/monitory/item/148-pos-monitor-tm-3315.html) when you touch, emulate mouse, but it's not sensor input (how on tablet for examle). And switcher "automatically show the touch keyboard" does't show. That's why I'm looking for another solution. Programmatically call keyboard by some event on C#